# Facebook wall post mention friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, parameters

How do I use the parameter `to` in a [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) post. My `to` parameter looks like this:

```
to = [{id: XXXXXXX, name: "Name "}, ....]
```

But it doesn't work and I don't receive any error from Facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post in Facebook with @mention ability using stream.publish?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5923434/how-to-post-in-facebook-with-mention-ability-using-stream-publish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set this parameter ... if you read a post object the "to" parameter is set if that post was posted to a users wall for example.

So for example if you (user 1) publish something to user 2's wall and read the post object afterwards the "from" would contain 1 and the "to" a 2. You can't add "recipients" like this, that's not what the "to" is for.

Comment: oops i got it, im lost in facebook documentation, where i can see the message create ? i know some parameters lije action, picture, link and etc. i want to give a badge to user in my aplication, im postin this message in application wall and tring to mention the user, there is another way  ?